# Script to disable an oracle trigger

Tags: sql, triggers, oracle11g

Before anything else, I have seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129288/how-do-i-find-all-code-triggers-from-an-oracle-database-that-relate-to-specific) here in stack. It says there how to list all the triggers, what I'm asking is script to disable (not delete/remove) all the triggers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question.  Unfortunately I can't test this locally, but something like this could potentially work.  Basically, declare a `CURSOR` to loop through all the triggers (for my purposes, I was testing with a couple TEST triggers).  Then use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` to execute dynamic sql.

```
DECLARE
CURSOR cur_trigger IS
SELECT 'ALTER TRIGGER ' ||
       table_owner ||
       '.' ||
       trigger_name ||
       ' DISABLE' SQLStatement
FROM all_triggers
WHERE trigger_name like '%TEST%';
sqlText cur_trigger%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN
  OPEN cur_trigger;
  LOOP
    FETCH cur_trigger INTO sqlText;
    EXIT WHEN cur_trigger%NOTFOUND;

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlText.SQLStatement;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE cur_trigger;
END;
```

And here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/85fda/4).   It doesn't work completely in Fiddle, but I believe that's because of Fiddle and not the code.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but sir, I don't really have a background on cursor, do you have anything like a simple update script?

Comment: There is no update script @Blackhat, you _have_ to do it this way or run the SELECT given and copy and paste the results before executing them.

Comment: I see, that means I have to work on it manually. As in one by one right?

Comment: And Thank you for sharing the [SQL Findle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/). The tool was very useful.